# Guardar variables latitud y longitud en la base de datos

Tags: java

aqui se instancia y declara las variables

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException, SQLException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        try 
(PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
            /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
     String Latitud=request.getParameter("Latitud");
     String Longitud=request.getParameter("Longitud");
```

aqui se conecta y realiza el insert a la base de datos

```
    ConexionBDFRS Conn = new ConexionBDFRS();// se crea el objeto de tipo ConexionBDFRS para tener acceso a la bd      
    Statement st0; 
    //try{
    String query="INSERT INTO mapa ( direccion, latitud, longitud) VALUES ('pedro','"+Latitud+"', '"+Longitud+"');" ; //aqui se escribe la instancia sql

                st0=Conn.getConnection().createStatement();//crea una instancia para ejecutar la query.
                st0.executeUpdate(query);// se ejecuta la instance creada con la query

                  Conn.cerrarConexion();
                  response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
```

Trato de guardar los siguientes atributos en mi base de datos pero la latitud y longitud me los marca null, como deberia hacerlo para que se me arregle ese error

Comment: ¿Qué tipo de dato son las columnas `latitud` y `longitud` en la base de datos? Si son del tipo `DOUBLE` o `DECIMAL` u otro numérico, tendrías que convertir los valores a ese tipo  y no usar las comillas simples `'` para rodear los valores en la sentencia de inserción. Revisa eso y nos dices. Cuando resuelvas el problema ten en cuenta que tu código es vulnerable a ataques de *Inyección SQL*. Deberías usar consultas preparadas para este caso.

Comment: si imprimes `request.getParameter("Latitud")` que te sale?

Answer (score 0):

Hace falta ver tu estructura de base de datos para dar con la respuesta ideal, ya que no sabemos que tipo de datos espera tu campo `latitud` y `longitud` , sin embargo por la naturaleza de los datos es posible que sean de tipo numérico mas espeficicamnte de tipo flotante en entonces si es el caso la respuesta seria la siguiente.

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException, SQLException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        try 
(PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
            /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
     String Latitud=request.getParameter("Latitud");
     String Longitud=request.getParameter("Longitud");

ConexionBDFRS Conn = new ConexionBDFRS();// se crea el objeto de tipo ConexionBDFRS para tener acceso a la bd      
    Statement st0; 
    //try{
    String query="INSERT INTO mapa ( direccion, latitud, longitud) VALUES ('pedro',"+Double.ParseDouble(Latitud)+", "+Double.ParseDouble(Longitud)+")" ; //aqui se escribe la instancia sql

                st0=Conn.getConnection().createStatement();//crea una instancia para ejecutar la query.
                st0.executeUpdate(query);// se ejecuta la instance creada con la query

                  Conn.cerrarConexion();
                  response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
```

También te recomiendo que en el diseño de base de datos si estos datos son obligatorios los cambies como `NOT NULL` ya que esto te podría hacer encontrar errores mas fácil.
Un saludo